# How to update a text in a line in a TextView in android?

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView in which I post status messages such as

```
Device found.
Device connected. 
Syncing with device (Syncing %).
Device disconnected.
```

I am using TextView.append() to post these status messages to TextView. How to update the percentage sync value in Syncing with device (syncing %) line(I do not want to append a new line with new sycn value). Is is possible and if not what View component should I use to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are using TextView.append() to post these messages.

But You should use TextView.setText () to update any value inside it.

```
TextView.setText("Syncing with device" + (Syncing %));
view.invalidate();           //for refreshment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ObservableField<String>()` as the value for the text field. Keep updating the value. Bind this value to the text view in xml using databinding.

Whenever you want to update the value just call `set("YOUR_VALUE")` on the field variable and set the text you want in the place of `YOUR_VALUE`. This will refresh your view automatically. It will be a clean, readable and maintainable code.

Example:

Kotlin File:

```
var syncFieldText = ObservableField<String>()
syncFieldText.set("Syncing.")
```

XML:

```
<layout>
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="YOUR_PACKAGE.MODEL_OR_VIEWMODEL" />
</data>
.
.
.
<ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView
        .
        .
        android:text="@{item.syncFieldText}"
        .
    />
</ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My example is just for one line. Same can be achieved for multiple lines also. You can update the entire text view itself using the same observable.